# Installing Python on a network drive for users with no write access

Tags: python, windows, networking, network-drive

I am wondering if it is possible, without any problems, to have Python installed on a network drive for use by multiple Windows users who have only read and execute rights. As far as I know, it is possible to add the python binaries to the PATH variable and run python on another drive without any problem, but I was wondering some things :

- I know you can install Python on another drive than your C: drive, but not sure if the same is possible with a network drive.
- Can this support concurrent users? Like two people running python scripts at the same time.
- Would users with no write privileges still be able to install python modules? I want only users with write access to the drive to be able to do this.
- Would this pose any problems with some modules?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a Linux user so can't test, but this seems like a common question and [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+on+a+network+drive) finds [lots](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/1ngql8/python_on_network_drive/) of [similar](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/KyWvdfaOxlU) questions with answers

to answer your questions to be best of my ability:

1. it should certainly support "concurrent users", the file server wouldn't even know the program is running, it'll just see devices on the network opening/reading the files
2. users obviously wouldn't be able to install things on network drives if they don't have write permission, but they should still be able to install modules locally (i.e. on their own machine) with something like [`pip install --user requests`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#user-installs)
3. I'm sure this would cause problems with **some** modules, but I wouldn't expect it to be many.  note that lots of modules have issues running under OSs that they weren't developed/tested in, and a lot of Python work happens on Unix/Linux/OSX machines

Comment: Well I wasn't able to find something applicable for my use case.

Comment: Anyways, this answers most things, but do you know if there's a way to restrict installation of modules on the user's PC? Even if the user has admin rights?

Comment: that kind of goes against how Python (and computers generally) work.  users can **always** download code and run it (especially if they have admin rights).  once users are explicitly writing code this is all the more obvious, e.g. they can just find the source of a "module" (e.g. on github) and copy/paste the relevant part of the code into their source file.  when they run it, they'll be "running" that module

Comment: Ok yea I get this. I am working in a very secured environment and we want to stay in control on what gets installed in PCs and was trying to find a way to convince IT that this could be done with Python, as they're not fond of the idea of getting modules from third-parties without prior approval. If this is impossible, I guess your answer would count as valid.

Comment: this is true with basically any language!  to pick one example, if you've got a modern web browser that has javascript enabled you can do basically the same.  check out the Filesystem API, and things like Pyodide give you access to the scientific python ecosystem running locally in the browser.  users could copy/paste code from modules elsewhere and run these.  you need to refine what you mean by "very secured" as it's very ambiguous, posting to https://security.stackexchange.com/ might help as well

Answer (score 0):

If you want everyone to have the same development enviorment:
Try creating a python virtualenv on the remote folder,so they can activate it when its required. https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/

But if want you want to do is to distribute an app and want everyone to have the same python, may be take a look at pyinstaller 'An application to convert python scripts into stand-alone binaries'

Comment: This is not really what I am looking for, as I want users to be able to develop Python programs without being able to add or modify modules/libraries.